# Python Imaging Library- Changing a colour for the last one encountered

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

As the title says, I'd like to be able to change the colour of a pixel/s with the last pixel of a different pixel encountered. For example, in the image below, I'd like to be able to replace the black pixels for orange ones, however simply saying if pixel == black, pixel = orange wont work, as I plan on applying the code to a more complicated image. The code below is my initial attempt: Any help is appreciated!

```
 for y in xrange(image_test.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(image_test.size[0]):
        currentPixel_2 = image_test.getpixel((x,y))
        if currentPixel_2 == (0,0,0):
            currentPixel_2 =
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a variable to hold the value of the previous pixel you encountered.

```
previous_pixel = None
for y in xrange(image_test.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(image_test.size[0]):
        currentPixel_2 = image_test.getpixel((x,y))
        if currentPixel_2 == (0,0,0) and previous_pixel:
            image_test.putpixel((x,y), previous_pixel)
        else:
            previous_pixel = currentPixel_2
```

I think most of the lines should be obvious here, but basically, if you're not on a black pixel, the last thing you do in the loop is assign the current pixel to `previous_pixel`, so your next pass through the loop, if it's black, you have the prior pixel value ready for use.

The line, `if currentPixel_2 == (0,0,0) and previous_pixel` is just in case your first pixel is black, and you don't have a `previous_pixel` value yet, I just skip it, though you can do what you want.  Another approach to this first pixel issue is to assign some value to `previous_pixel` before you start the loop.

Also, btw, here you are iterating over individual pixels, which will be fairly slow.  If you need to speed it up, you could do so with numpy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having issues getting your code to replace black pixels, maybe it's just me?

Comment: OK, fixed it with `putpixel`.  There's also the Pixel Access Object which should be faster, but I used putpixel since it's similar to getpixel.  See http://effbot.org/zone/pil-pixel-access.htm

Comment: Awesome! At first it wasn't working for me, but I forgot to put in .putpixel. Thanks for all of your help, it's very much appreciated!